# Persistence Context issues with Spring Data and bi-directional relationships

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

This issue arose while writing tests but might apply to application code too, and has left me with some questions.

(Questions are right at the bottom)

Summary of the situation:

- I was writing `DataJpaTests` tests to test a service layer object backed by some `CrudRepositories`.

  - Initially I seed the repository with some data, then make a service call.
  - Finally I query the repository to assert the state
- I have bi-directional One-to-Many relationships between a Parent and Child(ren)
- The child has its parent as part of the Natural Id
- In my assertion `parent.getChildren().contains(child)` failed as `false`, but it should be true.

```java
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // SEED
        Parent parent = Parent.builder()
                              .email("a@b.c").build();
        Child child = Child.builder()
                           .email("x@y.z").build();
        parent.addChild(child);
        parentRepository.save(parent);
        // ----
        // Irrelevant Service Code Omitted
        // ----
        // ASSERT
        parent = parentRepository.findById(parent.getId()).get();
        assertTrue(parent.getChildren().contains(child)); // FAILS
    }
```

This led me to debug and investigate.  It turned out that the parent's `children` set was exactly the same `PersistentSet` as before. And that's when I learned a little more about persistence contexts, though that knowledge is still very shallow.

The test passes if I do any of these:

1. Insert a duplicate `parentRepository.save(parent)`
2. Autowire an `EntityManager` and call `refresh(parent)` or a `flush(),clear()` combination.
3. I remove parent from the child's Natural Id
4. Re-order the operations in `addChild` so that the child is given a parent before being inserted into the parent's children set.

It is due to the fact that `Child` has `parent` in their hashcode and when initially inserted into the parent's children set, don't have the parent assigned and so the hashcode is different.

For reference, the entities:

```java
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @Builder
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    public void addChild(final Child child) {
        getChildren().add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    public void removeChild(final Child child) {
        getChildren().remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Parent parent = (Parent) o;
        return email.equals(parent.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(email);
    }
}
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @Builder
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_identifier")
    @NaturalId
    private Parent parent;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Child child = (Child) o;
        return email.equals(child.email) &&
                parent.equals(child.parent);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(email, parent);
    }
}
```

1. When would the `PersistentSet` be refreshed/rehashed if I didn't manually do it through `EntityManager`.
2. How can we be sure in application code that we're not dealing with persistence caching issue?
3. Is it bad to include the parent in the natural id of the child?
4. Is there any side-effect with reversing the operation order in `Parent::addChild`?

Thanks a lot for the advice in advance